# Scrolling and pinch disabled on mobile browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website which works fine on browsers on a laptop but when i start using the same on a mobile browser, i see that the only thing I am able to do on my mobile browser is to double tap to zoom in and be able to click and type.

I am not able to scroll or move the web page around to change the view port.

Has someone experienced the same problem before?

I am using bootstrap for this and the layout is responsive.

Please help.

Thank you

Comment: What is a system browser?

Comment: i meant on a laptop on chrome and safari

Comment: You will have to place the code and explain the problem you are facing in a manner that others can understand.

Comment: give us link so we also will try to test in mobile

Comment: Here is the link    http://intellivoyage.com/

Comment: @FahadUddin it is a website. I am not sure if the problem is within a certain part of the CSS or the website as a whole.